# MSaccess 2007 SQL complex query

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I have the following table columns and values...

```
ColA, ColB, ColC
b, 90, 1
p, 95, 5
p, 100, 6
p, 99, 6
p, 98, 6
b, 94, 5
b, 93, 1
b, 92, 3
o, 89, 3
b, 88, 4
```

I need the following result set:

```
ColA, ColB, ColC
b, 90, 1
b, 93, 1
p, 95, 5
o, 89, 3
```

Essentially, this is the lowest value for ColC where ColA is the same. So the lowest value for all the b's is 1, and it occurs in two rows. The lowest value for all the p's is 5, and the lowest value for all the o's is 3. ColB is a value to join on another table. So I do need a query that will join on another table over ColB.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
select mainTable.* from abcTable as mainTable inner join 
(select t.colA,min(t.colC) as minColC from  abcTable as t group by t.ColA) as minimumTable
on mainTable.colA=minimumTable.ColA and mainTable.colC=minimumTable.minColC
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks Eid!

Comment: Eid - I no longer want the second 'b' result row. I just want the row where ColA is grouped, that has the lowest ColC value; and if there is a tie, then the highest ColB determines the tie. And if they tie on ColC and ColB, then only return one row and I don't care which. Can you do that?

Comment: select distinct  mainTable.colA,max(mainTable.ColB),mainTable.ColC from abcTable as mainTable inner join 
(select t.colA,min(t.colC) as minColC from  abcTable as t group by t.ColA) as minimumTable
on mainTable.colA=minimumTable.ColA and mainTable.colC=minimumTable.minColC
group by mainTable.colA,mainTable.ColC

Answer (score 0):

Here you go!

```
with r1 as
(select *
,rank() over (partition by ColA order by ColC) fix
from aba
)

select * from r1 where fix = 1
```

Comment: Are you sure MS Access suports `RANK()`?

Comment: I don't think MSAccess 2007 supports this.

Comment: People still use MS Access? I thought this was MS SQL Server. Sorry!